# What are the differences between "want", "deserve" and "need"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, differences

When do I use *want*?
When do I use *need*?
When do I use *deserve*?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Want is a desire. Example: *I want to improve my grammar.*
- Deserve is being worthy of something good or bad as a result of one's behavior or actions.
  Examples: *Sarah deserves to win the prize.*
           *Brooke deserved to be punished for stealing candy.*
- Need is something that is vital or necessary for survival or overall well-being.
  Examples: *We need water to survive.*
        *I need your support in court.*